# dynamically setting the size of a textbox in a RDLC report

Tags: c#, textbox, width, rdlc

Can a textbox's width in a local RDLC report be set dynamically using C#? I would like to auto size the horizontal width of the text box based on the data it contains.

Answer (score 1):

Not easily.
http://gotreportviewer.com/ has examples for how to generate the RDLC dynamically from C#. Alternatively, you can try to add a script to your report that does that. I am not sure that the size and coordinates are in fact writable properties, though. I suspect that they are read-only.

Comment: Yea that's the answer I'm looking for, wither or not they are writable. I've looked into the reports LocalReport property for the textbox but can't seem to find anything.

Comment: Look at the answers to this question. Using a ReportViewerHelper may allow you to do that:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsreportcontrols/thread/c29e929d-573a-453e-8393-0f3e86065921/

Answer (score 1):

There's no solution for this. The dirty way is loading the rdlc xml file and edit it before loading the report: very dirty indeed.

Comment: Because these files are supposed to be changed in the designer only.